# How to Use Command Line Parameters by using JMeter?

Tags: automation, jmeter

I'm using Jmeter for testing APIs and I want to parametrize the project's path from the terminal and then I want to use this parameter in JMeter. I set testurl = test.com in basic terminal and i want to get this url by using testurl. The parameter that I've sent via Command Line : ./jmeter -n -t your_script.jmx -l -Jurl=$testurl in homebrew terminal. The parameter that I've used in httpsRequest --> Server name or IP; ${__P(url)}. But when I run my automation in the homebrew terminal, my test scripts are not going to URL that's been defined. Please help me!! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From first impression it seems what you are trying should work, but devil is in the detail. I would suggest you try:

1. Verify if the environment variable is set correctly use `export testurl=test.com` (removed spaces). Try verify using `echo $testurl`
2. Try debug sampler which should help you verify if JMeter is picking up the var correctly: https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/

Hope this helps.